# Script for setting Safari window position

Tags: terminal, mac, applescript, bash

I wrote a script to open Safari in a new tab with custom window size and window position. However, setting the window position is just not working. Below is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

loggedInUser="$(/bin/ls -la /dev/console | /usr/bin/cut -d " " -f 4)"
open /Applications/Safari.app/
osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\"
    make new document
    set URL of document 1 to \"http://link.com"
    set bounds of window 1 to {0, 0, 400, 700}
    set position of window 1 to {40, 50}
    end tell"
    activate
end tell"
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your script? The quotes seem to be wrong. In addition, what does "not working as expected" mean?

Comment: window positioning is just not working.

Comment: Can you fix the quotes and the escaping and try again?

Comment: Also, you probably need to either launch Safari from within AppleScript or sleep a few seconds between the `open` and the `osascript`

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `end tell` in there and your quoting is weird.

Try this.

```
set theXposition to 40
set theYposition to 50
set theXsize to 700
set theYsize to 700
tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    set URL of document 1 to "https://www.google.com"
    set bounds of window 1 to {theXposition, theYposition, theXsize, theYsize}
    activate
end tell
```

The arguments to the `bounds` property include the window position, so just set it there.

You may get bit if Safari isn't already running, and starting it causes it to restore your last set of session windows (you will get more than the one window you are creating).

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **shell script** *code* works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

loggedInUser="$(whoami)"
open -a "Safari"
osascript <<EOS
tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    set URL of document 1 to "http://link.com"
    set bounds of window 1 to {40, 50, 400, 700}
    activate
end tell
EOS
```

**Notes:**

The *value* for `bounds` may need to be adjusted for your liking, however, this is now a functioning *shell script* based on your *shell script*.

Comment: this works, but it doesn't allow the window to move to rightmost bottom corner of the screen, (just like a chat support window). the dimensions of size of the window and X,Y axis is somehow related related it seems

Comment: @mano RE: "this works, but it doesn't allow the window to move to rightmost bottom corner of the screen," --  Well nowhere in your question did you mention wanting to _position_ the _window_ in the lower right corner **and** I'm just using the information you presented in your question! If you want the _window_ elsewhere, then set it `bounds` accordingly. You could _size_ and _position_ the _window_ here you want it and then run `tell application "Safari" to return bounds of window 1` and use what it _returns_ for the _value_ of the `bounds` _property_ in your _script_.