# macos doesn't allow default safari window open rightmost bottom of the screen

Tags: macos, safari

This is almost the same question as here - [Script for setting Safari window position](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428238/script-for-setting-safari-window-position).

theXposition "doesn't allow the window to move to rightmost bottom corner of the screen, (just like a chat support window)"

Couldn't find any helpful information.

Comment: Your question must be significantly different to post a new question.  If you want more attention, offer a bounty.